# How to open exe file in maximized window using PHP?

Tags: php

The code below is from the official PHP site: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
It says it opens MS Paint in a maximized window, but that's not what happens.

I see in the Task Manager that MS Paint runs in the background, but I can't get it to open as a maximized window.

> Start MSPaint maximized and wait for you to close it before continuing the script:
>
> ```
> <?php 
> $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell"); 
> $oExec = $WshShell->Run("mspaint.exe", 3, true); 
> ?>
> ```

What should I do to open Paint in a maximized window?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Just saying nothing happens is not helpful. Please provide more details. Add some error checking. Check your logs. Does your IIS allow scripts permission to execute this code?

Comment: Even if this `mspaint.exe` runs, it will probably run in a background environment, most likely in another user space, and you won't see it. Check your process manager and show all processes you will probably see it running there.

Comment: If that is the case, you have to run this PHP script as a shell script in order to have it work.

Comment: I am using wamp and it not show any error ; yes ms paint run on background I am check through task manager  but not showing as maximised , So what's is the solution

Comment: Welcome! I have edited your question, re-ordered a few things, and edited your comment into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `shell_exec( $command . "> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");`

Update for Windows:

```
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("mspaint.exe", 3, false);
```

Third parameter setted to false tells the script it shouldn't wait the end of process before continuing.

Thanks to Havenard for explaination

Comment: Clearly, this is Windows. There is no `/dev/null`.

Comment: Oh, obviously! Sorry! Try to pass 0, false to Run instead of 3, true

Comment: The parameters should be correct, the second parameter `3` is a window display code, it tells the program it should start maximized. `0` tells it to hide the window, we don't want that. The third parameter `true` tells the script it should wait for the process to finish before countinuing.